# Accessing dot notated enums from a class in Swift

Tags: swift, enums, swiftui

I'm still fairly new to SwiftUI & Swift (from Javascript background) and I am working on creating a clone calculator app.

My CalculatorView currently has a button layout which is passed in to CalculatorActions and does what it needs to do to update the CalculatorView display.

```
// CalculatorView.swift 

// buttons = View layout with enum defined buttons
let buttons: [[Calculator]] = [
    [.ac, .plusMinus, .percent, .divide],
    [.seven, .eight, .nine, .multiply],
    [.four, .five, .six, .minus],
    [.one, .two, .three, .plus],
    [.zero, .period, .equal]
]

// var body
// ...
ForEach(buttons, id: \.self) { row in
    HStack(spacing: sizing.spacing) {
        ForEach(row, id: \.self) { button in
            Button(action: {
                actions.updateDisplay(button: button)
            }, label: {
                ButtonView(button: button, sizing: sizing)
            })
        }
    }
}
// ...
```

I have an enum I am using for my Calculator model like so:

```
// Calculator.swift (Enum Calculator Model)

enum Calculator: String {
    case ac, clear, plusMinus, percent, divide
    case seven, eight, nine, multiply
    case four, five, six, minus
    case one, two, three, plus
    case zero, period, equal

    var label: String {
        switch (self) {
            case .zero: return "0"
            case .one: return "1"
            case .two: return "2"
            case .three: return "3"
        // ...
```

I access these enums through the class in a separate file that I have with a controller where I often do comparisons or to access the label of whatever button was passed in like so:

```
// CalculatorActions.swift (Calculator Controller)

class CalculatorActions: ObservableObject {
    // ...
    func updateDisplay(button: Calculator) -> Void {
        // Clear
        if button == Calculator.ac {
            self.resetEverything()
            self.lastButtonPressed = button
            return
        }
    
        if button == Calculator.plusMinus {
        // ...
        self.append(Calculator.one.label)
```

I would love to clean up this and have the CalculatorActions controller class, which is in a separate file, essentially do enum comparisons like this

```
// CalculatorActions.swift (Calculator Controller)

class CalculatorActions: ObservableObject {
    // ...
    func updateDisplay(button: Calculator) -> Void {
        // Clear
        if button == .ac {
            self.resetEverything()
            self.lastButtonPressed = button
            return
        }
    
        if button == .plusMinus {
        // ...
        self.append(.one.label)
```

but for obvious reasons, you can't extend a class with an enum.

Essentially, within CalculatorActions.swift, I want to be able to use enum from Calculator.swift `.plusMinus` instead of `Calculator.plusMinus`.

If possible or not, please school me.

Comment: Please share more code of `CalculatorActions`.

Comment: Taking a step back, could you explain precisely what the enum is meant to model, and what exactly `CalculatorActions` is trying to do with its values? From what I can tell, a more appropriate name for it would be something like `CalculatorButton`

Comment: @pawello2222 I added more to the question. Not sure if it adds value but hopefully it helps.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica The enum is modeling the the CalculatorButtons and providing extra context such as label name (which could simply be text or a systemName string for image), a few boolean options for understanding if this is an operations button, printable number, and also provides color context for the button itself.

Comment: @ReyHaynes That sounds like it should be a collection of objects of `CalculatorButton` type, not just a single enum. Each of these objects stores their name, image, etc. Then you can replace your switch statement with polymorphism

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Interesting. Maybe when I get deeper into Swift/SwiftUI, I'll double back on the approach I took for this clone Calculator project I decided to make just to learn.

Comment: That doesn't really have much to do with SwiftUI, and that's pretty much the same thing you would do in Javascript: you would model these real-world entities (calculator buttons) with objects that store the data necessary to perform their role (to define how they're displayed, what kind of action they kick off, etc.)

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I ended up uploading my work via GitHub. https://github.com/ReyHaynes/SwiftUI-Calculator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Swift can automatically infer types**

In your function:

```
func updateDisplay(button: Calculator) { // no need to specify `Void` explicitly 
    // Clear
    if button == .ac { // you can skip `Calculator` and use `.ac`, Swift knows that button is of type `Calculator`
        resetEverything()
        lastButtonPressed = button // no need to use self (individual preference)
        // you don't need to return from `Void` function
    }

    if button == .plusMinus { // again, you can replace `Calculator.plusMinus` with `.plusMinus`
    // ...
    self.append(.one.label) // `append` accepts a `string` parameter, you may need to make it accept `Calculator` parameter instead and call it like `append(.one)`
}
```

Basically you can use `.plusMinus` instead of `Calculator.plusMinus` wherever Swift is able to infer the type automatically. Which can be when comparing `.plusMinus` with another `Calculator` variable, passing the `Calculator` parameter...

Just remember Swift needs to *know* you're passing the `Calculator` variable.

---

Note that you can specify a `rawValue` directly:

```
enum Calculator: String {
    case one = "1", two = "2", three = "3", plus = "+"
    ...

    var label: String {
        rawValue
    }
}
```

I'd recommend also renaming `Calculator` to something more descriptive. It's not a calculator, but a part of it (`CalculatorItem`, `CalculatorButton`...).

Comment: Thanks! removing `Calculator` from the inferred comparison `button` actually works. For some reason, it was crashing the app on Xcode 12 beta yesterday.

I guess I'll just include `Calculator` with append since I only want to deal with the string format because I also use it for other purposes such as calculation evaluation.

I am also so used to using `self` from my javascript background, nice to know it's optional.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's an answer (as far I can understand question):

```
enum Calculator: String {
    case ac, clear, plusMinus, percent, divide
    case seven, eight, nine, multiply
    case four, five, six, minus
    case one, two, three, plus
    case zero, period, equal
    
    var label: String {
        return self.rawValue
    }
}
```

If you want assign some var to enum element, this var must have defined type:

```
var calc: Calculator
calc = .eight
```

and if your `append` function is defined as

```
func append(_ calc: Calculator) {...}
```

you can call it:

```
append(.eight)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I updated my question to reflect more of what I was looking for. I essentially would like to access `.eight` from a different class (in aa different file) without accessing it with `Calculator.eight` just to reduce the code a bit.